# redirect STDERR output to file

Tags: linux, time, stdout, stdin, stderr

How I can redirect output to file

```
top -b -n 1 -d1 | grep "Cpu(s)" |awk '{print $2}' | awk -F. '{print $1}' >> logs.txt
time echo "scale=5000; 4*a(1)" | bc -lq 2>&1 | grep real |  cut -f2)  2> >> logs.txt
free |grep Mem |awk '{print $3/$2 * 100.0}' >> logs.txt
```

but I get logs from time command executes it wipes previous logs from script, I tried with /usr/bin/time but no luck how I can redirect. 2> >> logs.txt or 2>&1 >> logs.txt

Please help me here.

Regards,

SAMURAI

Comment: I'm not sure if this is how you want, but if you try something like this:
`cat error.tx > cat err.tx 2>> errors.txt`
I tried that, and inside the file **errors.txt** I get the stderr output like **No such file of directory**

Comment: As you can see, I used `>` instead of `|`